# Ruby: ignoring nil?

Tags: ruby, json, hash

I am trying to parse a bunch of json attributes and assign them to an hash. The json has a ton of levels to it:

```
player[:position]=player["positions"]["primary_position"]["position"]["name"]
```

The problem I'm encountering is that any one of these levels may be nil, which means that I need to write four separate nil? checks just to extract the value.

I don't care about the `nil` values -- it would be fine if the array just recorded them as `" "` or something similar.

Is there any way I can turn off `nil` errors for this particular type of thing? Or should I run the whole thing thru a `rescue` method that returns the value I want in the event of `nil`?

Comment: if `nil`, then expected output ? suppose `layer["positions"]["primary_position"]` giving `nil`, then what the next step you are thinking? I need that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
player[:position]=player["positions"]["primary_position"]["position"]["name"] rescue " "
```

This would return the desired value, or " " if something is nil.

Comment: In a full rescue block this would be true, but isn't required if you simply want an empty string returned. This method is more elegant than an entire block, correct?

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [andand](http://andand.rubyforge.org/) gem, which is similar to the [Maybe monad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29#The_Maybe_monad).

```
player[:position] = player.andand["positions"].andand["primary_position"].andand["position"].andand["name"]
```

This is a *guarded method invocation*. It only continues to send the method to the object if the result is not `nil` otherwise it returns `nil`. This way the chained invocation is stopped the moment one of the them returns `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach is to use `inject` thusly:

```
path  = %w[positions primary_position position name]
value = path.inject(player) { |h, k| h && h[k] }
```

You'd adjust the `h && h[k]` test to suite your specific needs, that one assumes that you won't have to worry about non-Hash values inside `h`. You make it as elaborate as you need.

You could even patch that into `Hash` if you were doing this sort of thing all the time:

```
class Hash
  def follow_path(*path)
    # You could also path.flatten if you're not expecting Array keys
    path.inject(self) { |h, k| h && h[k] }
  end
end

value = person.follow_path(*%w[positions primary_position position name])
```

or toss it into a private utility method:

```
private

  def follow_path(h, *path)
    # Assuming you're not using Array keys...
    path.flatten.inject(h) { |h, k| h && h[k] }
  end
```

and then:

```
value = follow_path(person, %w[positions primary_position position name])
```